# Android integer.parseInt() doesn't work for single-digit integers

Tags: java, android, parseint

I'm using Android Eclipse Indigo Release 2 and I'm having problems with the parseInt() function. I have a string buffer that I'm parsing to get an Integer value. The problem is that it only works correctly with a 2-digit integer but not with a single digit. I further attempted to use the "radix" clause to correct the problem, but no luck.  If I hard-code the string with the radix it works:

```
            case PIN_STATE:
            int pin_state = 0; 
            String statebuff = (String) msg.obj;
            if (msg.arg1 > 0) {
            try{                
            pin_state=Integer.parseInt(statebuff,10); //Doesn't work for single-digit integers
            pin_state=Integer.parseInt("01",10); // equals = 1 hard code works below correctly

             } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
             return; 
            }
             switch (pin_state){ 

            case 1:  //RESYNC_THERMO_ON:  //Sync module state - thermostat is on 
                    ThermoCheck.setChecked(true);
                    ThermoTxt.setText(R.string.ThermoOn);
                ThermoTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                ThermoTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                fanSpeedTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case 12: //work great without any modifications to the parseInt() function above
                            ThermoCheck.setChecked(true);
                    ThermoTxt.setText(R.string.ThermoOn);
                ThermoTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                ThermoTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                fanSpeedTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

            default:  //Do something
           }
```

}

Comment: hmm... try `.valueOf`

Comment: "doesn't work for single-digit integers": do you really think a bug like this would not have been discovered up to now?

Comment: I'm new and unseasoned Henry. But to answer your question - NO. when one isn't programming in this space a lot he/she isn't conscious of many elementary things. Here is one for you: the bible states that Jesus rose "again" according to the scriptures. Well the 64k question many should have asked BUT haven't is: "when was the first or previous time he rose from the grave?"  Unless we work/study diligently in certain paradigms in life, we tend to be unconscious of the obvious (hidden right under our nose)

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is wrong,

```
String statebuff = "1";
int v = Integer.parseInt(statebuff,10);
System.out.println(v);
```

prints 1. Your `statebuff` value isn't what you think, my assumption is it has a space.

```
 int v = Integer.parseInt(statebuff.trim()); // <-- add a trim call, also parseInt is 
                                             //     decimal by default so 10 is 
                                             //     redundant.
```

Comment: also you can use Integer.parseInt(statebuff). radix is 10 by default

Comment: I tested it with your changes and it seems to fix the issue. it makes perfect sense. But surprisingly the NumberFormatException isn't thrown when the program attempts to parseInt the string value containing the space. Thanks Elliott.